# SWTError: Not implemented [multiple displays]

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to open a [SWT-file-browser](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SimpleFileBrowserinSWTTable.htm) in on button click event.

```
tnAddFiles.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                     new FileBrowser();

                }
            });
```

I am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Not implemented [multiple displays]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDisplay(Display.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:807)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:690)
    at com.rawzor.ui.FileBrowser.<init>(FileBrowser.java:34)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are using the implementation from that website. If this is the case, this code uses the following line:

```
Display display = new Display();
```

which will initialize a new `Display`. Since your application already has a `Display` this will lead to the

> SWTError: Not implemented [multiple displays]

The solution would be to either use the built-in classes [`FileDialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FFileDialog.html) for file selection:

```
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.OPEN);
fd.setText("Open file");
fd.setFilterPath("C:/");
String[] filterExt = { "*.txt", "*.doc", ".rtf", "*.*" };
fd.setFilterExtensions(filterExt);
String file= fd.open();
System.out.println(file);
```

or [`DirectoryDialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FDirectoryDialog.html) for directory selection:

```
DirectoryDialog dlg = new DirectoryDialog(shell);
dlg.setText("Choose directory");
dlg.setFilterPath("C:/");
String dir = dlg.open();
System.out.println(dir);
```

Comment: +1 @Baz Thanks, once again for the help, you real SWT champ. [Link is helpful](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: @HDdeveloper That link is only for Swing, not for SWT.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a Shell instance. Do you know how I can fix that? Is there a Window class or something similar? Thanks.

Comment: @SamSaint-Pettersen Please post your question as a separate one. Also make sure to include a code example and all the references.

Comment: @Baz: Will do. Thanks.

Comment: @Baz: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420963/org-eclipse-swt-swterror-not-implemented-multiple-displays